# Intellij: Search console output

Tags: intellij-idea, development-environment

Up until version 10, intellij enabled searching text in the console window. From version 11 this option is not available anymore.

Is there any configuration to enable that? A plugin maybe? This is very useful for me and I miss this function...

-- EDIT --

I'm using the community edition of Intellij

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in the console:

[image: Search]

Comment: That would too easy, wouldn't it? This is how I used to do that in old versions - it's not working...

Comment: I've just took this screenshot from IDEA 12.1.4, so it works. Maybe your Find action has different shortcut? Verify in `Settings` | `Keymap`. Also, what Run configuration type do you use and what console do you search?

Comment: Thanks. CTRL+F had some kind of conflict. I used ALT + F and now it's working!

Comment: It seems eclipse bindings set Ctrl+F to Replace instead of Find.

Comment: @Celos which shortcut are you using then?

Comment: @fascynacja I switched Ctrl+F back to Find and, after going over the list of familiar search/replace related shortcuts from Eclipse, mapped Replace to Alt+F. All the others I could think of (Ctrl+H etc) are already meaningfully mapped.

Comment: I'm using 14.1.2 at the moment, and use the IdeaVim plugin. Ctrl+F in the console window isn't working. It's mapped to Find in the keymap. Perhaps there is a bug where when using the IdeaVim plugin, when the focus is on the console, all the keys are taken away for vim, even though the vim keys aren't used inside the console.
I just figured a work around for this. Add a keymap for Ctrl+Shift+Alt+F mapping to the Find action...

Comment: This solution don't work on the terminal for the specified version. It's the main part of the issue.

Comment: @sab Terminal and Run console are completely independent features, however Ctrl+F also works for Terminal tool window in the latest version.

Comment: Not supported in IJ 16.2. Not even able to search a text in console and they call this the most intelligent IDE?

Comment: Working well in IJ 2017.1.3 when a shortcut is assigned in Settings - Keymap - Main Menu - Edit - Find - Find...

Comment: The VIM plugin breaks this.   Ctrl+F is mapped to Find.... but the VIM plugin seems to absorb it, even if you're not in an editor window.   Using Alt-F3 works.

Answer (score 36):

Override the keymap for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to "Find" which was mapped to some other find.

To be more specific, in Settings - Keymap go to Main Menu - Edit - Find - Find... and make sure that a Shortcut is assigned here.

Comment: To be more specific, in Settings - Keymap go to Main Menu - Edit - Find - Find... and make sure that a Shortcut is assigned here.

Answer (score 13):

Check you key map settings. Like in my case - I have eclipse key mapping and there is CTRL+F set to "edit\Replace" not to "edit\Find", and the "edit\Find" has no key binding at all, that's why it is not working in console.

Answer (score 12):

Go to File -> Settings -> Keymap -> Main menu -> Edit -> Find -> Find... (right click on it) -> add keyboard shortcut. 
It's not set by default so you have to set it manually.

Answer (score 10):

CTRL+F is by default for Replace that is not supported in console for IntelliJ.

Click on console and Use CTRL+K it is used for find in intelliJ

Comment: Yes. It worked for me. I am using this :-  Runtime version: 11.0.13+7-b1751.25 amd64

Answer (score 5):

I'm using **Eclipse key mapping** in IntelliJ. The shortcut to search the console is `Ctrl + Shift + G`. By default it would search the word where the cursor is pointing.

Answer (score 2):

I was encountering the same issue while I was using `vim` in *IntelliJ 2018.3.4*.

After I **disabled** the *Tools -> Vim Emulator*, I could then search in Console using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

---

#### Updated

In macOS, I just could use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> without disabling the emulator.

<sub>Perhaps that's why developers are using macOS more.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

For those who have vim plug-in enabled.

Go to Editor->Vim Emulation and check keymaps. Make sure Ctrl + F is handled by IDE and not by Vim.

After setting that, I am able to search the console by Ctrl + F and keep vim enabled.